# How to first merge and then crop rasters in python

Tags: python, rasterio

Currently I have to create a lot of tiles (defined by a shapely multipolygon) from a large number of rasters.

Each tile is a polygon and the rasters are simply tiff files on my disk.

Right now I first find all the filenames of the rasters intersecting the tile adn put them in a list.

I then apply the following procedure

```
images = []
for file in files:
   images.append(rasterio.open( file)

mosaic =  merge(images)
```

The remaining step would be to crop the 'mosaic' raster with the shapely polygon that defines the tile.

However by performing the merge step the mosaic became a numpy array, so I cannot apply the mask method to it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the bounds parameter of rasterio.merge.merge() with your shapely polygon of a specific tile.

```
array_clipped_mosaic, out_transform = rasterio.merge.merge(datasets, bounds = *polygon.bounds)
```

Comment: Thank you that is an elegant way of doing it!